# Is it unethical to divulge results of a COVID test to my team?

Tags: ethics, manager, covid-19

## Background

At my workplace, we have, in my opinion, an issue with being transparent about where COVID exposure is.  I understand the rationale of being careful with how information is communicated:  HIPPA must be adhered to at all times. But this is my own medical information that I choose to divulge.

However, there is one person on my team who has a compromised immune system due to diabetes and is deathly afraid of COVID to say the least. I recently tested positive for COVID and told the nurse, my HR manager, and my team.  I wanted them to know because I want to make sure they know where possible COVID exposure is. Especially so my immuno compromised teammate has a better awareness of where the danger is.

## Issue

My HR manager recently called me and ordered me to in the future not tell me team about my COVID results.  The nurse told me in a less direct manner "no one needs to know except me", I did not understand that as not sending results, and it seems my HR manager sees that misunderstanding.

However, at the same time, as a help to my team, I really find this order problematic.  I want my immune compromised teammate to be aware of where possible exposure could occur, should I deal with this in the future. This leads to my question...

## Question

Would it be the ethical thing to do, albeit against protocol, to tell my team about my COVID result in the future, so long as my HR manager wouldn't know?

Comment: I would re-consider working for a company where HR is asking you not to tell your coworkers that you have a deadly highly infectious disease.

Comment: @sf02 Already been looking for new jobs since the beginning of the year...

Comment: @bharal, does this question not fall within the guidelines mentioned here https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/454/91777?

Comment: @SolarMike I still work in this team, but I am also looking for a new job.  The two are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @bharal I had no idea I was Covid positive until two days after my last day of work before quarantine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many things to learn about those around us and work during this pandemic. One of them is how little your employer gives a damn about you, or their employees.

Your story for me is incredible because you were told, over the phone (so no paper trail) to hide the fact you are covid positive, *knowing* that one of their employees, could quite possibly die over it..to squeeze out some extra dollars from them.

But what’s incredible about it, is how short sighted they are about the whole dynamics of it all.

The mere contact tracing that will come out of it, and how they don’t even appear to be aware what will happen to them, when word gets out, that they deliberately hid information, and **you** went along with it, and a dozen coworkers got sick and an immuno-compromised coworker got severely ill or died.

Unfortunately you’ll be dragged along with it....

It is in your moral interest to tell your immuno-compromised coworker at the bare minimum that you tested positive, and they should get tested too, you may want to consider reading your employee handbook, if one exists, to see if there is anything in there that could be used against you, though i highly doubt there is a section dedicated to hiding pandemic infections from coworkers in there, you should keep any and all documentation about this, and get it in writing from your HR and nurse, that they specifically meant, that this covid situation should be kept ‘between you’..if they can’t provide that with their names on it...well it’s clear that they arn’t supposed to be telling you this to begin with.

Afterwards in your shoes, *I* would purposely ensure everyone I knew at the company, knew I was positive, and that HR and the company nurse were trying to hide it from them...and likely try to make it a PR nightmare for the company in the newspaper...but that is only what I would do, since the fallout wouldn’t be one I personally would have a problem with. This is not a suggestion, for you, simply what I would do.  it might cause lots of bridge burning and financial loss.

Answer (score 1):

Your company will have a policy on this kind of situation, so refer to that. Failing that, you should really talk with your manager before doing anything else.

In the meantime, stay at home.